# Excel - Importing listobject table in another workbook to an array

Tags: excel, vba, excel-tables, listobject

The code below is meant to import data from a defined table in another workbook to process in this workbook, after which it will clear the contents of the table in the source workbook.

It gives me the following error:
`Object variable not set (Error 91)`

I tried the following code to import the data into the array. I would expect to be able to interact with the data in the array after the other workbook has been closed.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim arrPC As Variant
    Dim PCwb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim PCws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MainSheet")    
    Set PCwb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Path\OtherWorkbook")
    Set PCws = PCwb.Sheets("ImportSheet")
    
    arrPC = PCws.ListObjects("ImportTable").DataBodyRange.Value

    If not isnull(arrPC) Then
        PCws.ListObjects("ImportTable").DataBodyRange.ClearContents
    End If
    
    PCwb.Close

End Sub
```

Forgive my inability to add this as in-code comment, but the code breaks on this line:

`arrPC = PCws.ListObjects("ImportTable").DataBodyRange.Value`

Comment: Closing quotations marks are missing for `"ImportTable"`. Please be aware that ws is dimmed as variant. You have to explicitly state the data type like this: `Dim ws as Worksheet, PCws as Worksheet`

Comment: When opening a workbook, you need to use the full path e.g. `C:\Test\OtherWorkbook.xlsx`. Please explain the purpose of *"Initialized"* and why you're using `A4:J...` instead of `.DataBodyRange` when clearing the source table.

Comment: Thanks @Ike I picked up on that in my edit. I have anonymized some of the naming and the paths. I'll edit the above to indicate it as such.

Comment: @VBasic2008 I've amended the *initialized* and *range* component, it was leftover code from troubleshooting. To be honest the programme didn't even run far enough for me to test that.

Comment: Are there data in the table - you could check for that with `If not PCws.ListObjects("ImportTable").DataBodyRange is nothing then`

Comment: @Ike Thank you that seems to have solved the issue. I'll open a new ticket if something else breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Import Data From Table in a Closed Workbook

- It is infested with various checks. Remove the ones that seem redundant (ridiculous) to you.

```vb
Sub ImportTableData()
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Import Table Data"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Const SRC_FILE_PATH As String = "C:\Test\OtherWorkbook.xlsx"
    Const SRC_SHEET_NAME As String = "ImportSheet"
    Const SRC_TABLE_NAME As String = "ImportTable"
    Const DST_SHEET_NAME As String = "MainSheet"
    
    If Len(Dir(SRC_FILE_PATH)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The file """ & SRC_FILE_PATH & """ was not found.", _
            vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks.Open(SRC_FILE_PATH)
        
    Dim sws As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
        Set sws = swb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET_NAME)
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    If sws Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The worksheet """ & SRC_SHEET_NAME _
            & """ was not found in workbook """ & swb.Name & """!", _
            vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        GoTo ProcExit
    End If
        
    Dim slo As ListObject
    On Error Resume Next
        Set slo = sws.ListObjects(SRC_TABLE_NAME)
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    If slo Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The table """ & SRC_TABLE_NAME _
            & """ was not found in worksheet """ & sws.Name _
            & """ of workbook """ & swb.Name & """!", _
            vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        GoTo ProcExit
    End If
    
    If slo.DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The table """ & slo.Name & """ is empty!", _
            vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        GoTo ProcExit
    End If
    
    If slo.ShowAutoFilter Then
        If slo.AutoFilter.FilterMode Then slo.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    End If
    
    Dim sData() As Variant
    
    With slo.DataBodyRange
        If .Cells.CountLarge = 1 Then
            ReDim sData(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
            sData(1, 1) = .Value
        Else
            sData = .Value
        End If
    End With
    
    slo.DataBodyRange.ClearContents ' '.Delete' looks more appropriate
    swb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Set swb = Nothing

    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook

    Dim dws As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
        Set dws = dwb.Sheets(DST_SHEET_NAME)
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    If dws Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The worksheet """ & DST_SHEET_NAME _
            & """ was not found in workbook """ & dwb.Name & """!", _
            vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        GoTo ProcExit
    End If
    
    ' Do your thing, e.g.:
    MsgBox "My destination worksheet is named """ & dws.Name _
        & """ and is located in the workbook containing this code named """ _
        & dwb.Name & """." & vbLf & "I'm going to process data retrieved " _
        & "in an array that has " & UBound(sData, 1) & " rows and " _
        & UBound(sData, 2) & " columns.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE

ProcExit:
    On Error Resume Next
        If Not swb Is Nothing Then swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll be sure to apply some of this in code further down.

The simple answer is what @Ike provided - the table didn't have data, so I added a check for that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Ike for providing this,

The issue was indeed that my import table did not have data, so I modified the if statement as follows:

```
If Not PCws.ListObjects("ImportTable").DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
    arrPC = PCws.ListObjects("ImportTable").DataBodyRange.Value
    PCws.ListObjects("ImportTable").DataBodyRange.ClearContents
End If
```